# Resize kubernetes cluster with a different machine type?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to add a new node in existing kubernetes cluster, but with a different machine type. For the new node I will add label for it so that only some application will run on it.

I tried the following command

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed resize CONTAINER_GROUP --zone ZONE --size 5 --machine-type n1-standard-8
```

And it returns an error

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instance-groups.managed.resize) unrecognized
>   arguments:   --machine-type   n1-standard-8

**How can I add a new node into existing kubernetes cluster with a different machine type?**

Comment: This question was previously answered on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302233/resize-instance-types-on-container-engine-cluster/31303169#31303169).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around the single machine-type restriction by creating a new instance group with a (modified) copy of GKE's instance template. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303169/805800) for more details. Note that later you may need to manually upgrade that instance group (instead of using GKE's Node Upgrade API).

Answer (score 7):

- Create a new node pool with a custom machine type, disk-size, num-nodes and with any other required parameters.
- All steps are at
  [**Google Container Engine GKE node pools**](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/05/introducing-Google-Container-Engine-GKE-node-pools.html).

Comment: Followed that guide and successfully started migrating pods from one old node to the newer one

Answer (score 0):

This is something not available today with Google Container Engine. You can only have identical nodes in the cluster.

Generally, you can change the instance type but not when instance is part of the instance group. Even if you could change the instance type in the instance group (which you can't), the GKE doesn't support yet mixed clusters.

Comment: But the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance) says I can change the machine type of a stopped node.  I tried that and it says `ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.set-machine-type) Some requests did not succeed:
 - The resource 'xxxx' is not ready`.  So Google disabled that?

Comment: Generally, you can change the instance type but not when instance is part of the instance group. Even if you could change the instance type in the instance group (which you can't), the GKE doesn't support yet mixed clusters.

Comment: So if I want to upgrade the machine type, I need create a new cluster?  Seems unreasonable for production environment since that would lead to downtime

Comment: @user325320 - unfortunately, this is the situation today.